# Bypass entity framework's schema validation?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a situation where I need to make changes to my Model (code-first) and mirror the changes manually on the database.  Migrations are not an option.  Unfortunately, this causes entity framework to throw an exception when it validates the schema against the model (using the __MigrationHistory table).  Is there a way to disable the schema validation that entity framework does?  I'm using EF 4.3 specifically.

Comment: are you planning to use migrations after you do the changes? If not you may consider just deleting the __MigrationHistory table...

Comment: Doing this results in an exception being thrown: `Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.`

Comment: OK. I think then you need just set the Initializer to null. In that case it should not matter whether you have the table or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could create your own implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer` that does nothing, and use `Database.SetInitializer()`.